# When stubbing a method in Mockito, should I use the original instance or the stubbed instance for my tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a Service method I want to test:

```
public ScheduleView createSchedule(ScheduleView scheduleView) throws ValidationException {
    scheduleView = (ScheduleView) createObject(scheduleView, ScheduleBean.class);
    sendNotificationScheduleDataChangedToSchedulerDaemon();
    return scheduleView;        
}
```

the `sendNotificationScheduleDataChangedToSchedulerDaemon()` method makes a connection to a remote service named ServerService, which is not what you want during a unit test. The remote service isn't running during the Unit tests, so the connection fails. I preferably want to stub this method using Mockito so it doesn't get called:

```
public void testCRUOperations() {
    // Create the service 
    ScheduleService scheduleService = (ScheduleService) ServiceFactory.getInstance().createService(ScheduleService.class);
    ScheduleService scheduleServiceSpy = spy(ScheduleService.class);
    doNothing().when(scheduleServiceSpy).sendNotificationScheduleDataChangedToSchedulerDaemon();
```

now, my question is, how should I call the createSchedule() method so the stubbed method doesn't get executed?

```
scheduleView = scheduleService.createSchedule(newscheduleView);
```

or

```
scheduleView = scheduleServiceSpy.createSchedule(newscheduleView);
```

I've tried them both, but the stubbed method still gets executed and I still get `ConnectException` in my log.

I've checked other questions on here as well as the Mockito framework site, but I can't figure it out. What's the correct way to stub a method?

Comment: I'm not sure about the stubbing but everything seems to indicate that a refactor should be done. This issue is a clear indicator that the method in question should be abstracted out into an inject-able dependency.

Comment: What you've done looks correct.  I'm not sure why the `sendNotificationScheduleDataChangedToSchedulerDaemon` method still got called after you stubbed it.  Is it either final or private by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment so putting it here.

I'm not sure about the stubbing but everything else seems to indicate that a refactor should be done. This issue is a clear indicator that the method in question or to what it is interacting with is tightly coupled and should be abstracted out into an inject-able dependency

```
public interface NotificationService {
    void sendNotificationScheduleDataChangedToSchedulerDaemon();
}

public class ScheduleService {
    private NotificationService notificationService;

    public ScheduleService(NotificationService notificationService) {
        this.notificationService = notificationService;
    }

    public ScheduleView createSchedule(ScheduleView scheduleView) throws ValidationException {
        scheduleView = (ScheduleView) createObject(scheduleView, ScheduleBean.class);
        notificationService.sendNotificationScheduleDataChangedToSchedulerDaemon();
        return scheduleView;        
    }
}
```

The dependency can now be mocked during unit tests so that it does not hit the actual service and concrete implementation will be used in production code.

Comment: I totally agree, however, we use the Factory pattern (`ServiceFactory.getInstance().createService (ScheduleService.class)`), and the ServerService itself has extra parameters for the ServiceFactory.getInstance() call, so having to inject the service like you suggest means that our classes that call the ScheduleService methods lose separation of concerns.

Comment: The service factory is not smart enough to identify the dependencies of the services it is creating? You should look into Dependency Inject.

Comment: The service factory could act as your IoC container.

Comment: You don't have separation of concerns. Use an abstract factory that's injected and mockable and you will.